# Plotting several time series graphs in R

Tags: r

Can anyone help.  I have a large data set and need to plot several time series graphs.

I have used the following but it placed it all on one graph and was hard to read.

```
ts.plot(bc,gpars= list(col=rainbow(10)))
```

The data is below if anyone can help?

```
TIME      15         16           17           18          20          22          23
08:00:00 130.4905899    15.44164769 948.9185939 6211.837354 1071.730556 10.08920076 7.793301031
11:00:00 125.7301547    18.87143833 991.0009783 6304.471569 1082.126629 10.80475415 7.857773565
14:00:00 153.3779662    17.63335938 949.1741247 6209.524186 1079.102756 10.68438383 8.326058855
17:00:00 132.3256891    15.8961511  917.0452991 6123.402395 1081.166439 10.41007094 7.856372445
20:00:00 130.6405835    15.28122651 917.0229181 6135.679239 1084.589394 10.70688202 7.741277402
08:00:00 124.1484465    17.14357927 948.9060481 6126.791479 1085.907147 10.76713085 7.810187162
08:00:00 161.0455657    17.10409992 881.4517913 5839.73355  1073.585164 9.925269955 7.987206082
08:00:00 165.645823     16.45928764 860.4285647 5781.612679 1073.439013 10.01297791 7.983672272
```

I have been search and cant find what I need to do?

Thanks in advance.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- read.csv("Strep_time_series_NBS.csv", header = TRUE, row.names = NULL)
timestamps <- lubridate::dmy_h(c(3008201808, 3008201811,     3008201814,    3008201817, 3008201820,3108201808, 0309201808, 1009201808))

df_fix_times <- df %>%
  mutate(TIME=timestamps)

df_tidy <- df_fix_times %>%
  gather(series, value, -TIME)

ggplot(df_tidy, aes(TIME, value, group =series))+
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~series, scales = "free_y")

library(sqldf)

df2=sqldf("What needs to go in here?")   


library(officer);library(ggplot2);library(magrittr);library(rvg)


doc <- read_pptx()
for (i in 1:nrow(df))
{
  data_graph_ind=df_tidy[(df_tidy$series==df[i,1]),]
  doc <- add_slide(doc, layout = "Two Content", master = "Office Theme")
  doc <- doc %>% 
  ph_with_text(type = "title",df2[i,1]) 

  doc <- doc %>%
  ph_with_vg(doc, ggobj=ggplot(data = data_graph_ind, aes(x = TIME, y    =      value)) + 
             geom_line()+geom_point(),type="body")
  print(doc,target="C:/path/example.pptx")

  }
```

Thanks

Comment: You may use "Officer" and "ggplot2" packages to create separate slides for each graph in one power point document.
You can use read_pptx (from officer), ggplot (to create graph using ggplot2), add_slide (from officer), ph_with_text (from officer), ph_with_vg (from officer) and print (from officer)

Comment: I have changed the times to make them easier to read.  The last three 08:00:00 are completed on another date.  So I need R to keep the order of the columns, which is seems to like to change :(

Answer (score 1):

(EDIT: updated to use the revised sample data with hour times.)

Here's one approach. First load the tidyverse and read in the data:

```
library(tidyverse)   

df <- read.table(
    header = TRUE, row.names = NULL, text =
      "TIME      15         16           17           18          20          22          23
08:00:00 130.4905899    15.44164769 948.9185939 6211.837354 1071.730556 10.08920076 7.793301031
             11:00:00 125.7301547    18.87143833 991.0009783 6304.471569 1082.126629 10.80475415 7.857773565
             14:00:00 153.3779662    17.63335938 949.1741247 6209.524186 1079.102756 10.68438383 8.326058855
             17:00:00 132.3256891    15.8961511  917.0452991 6123.402395 1081.166439 10.41007094 7.856372445
             20:00:00 130.6405835    15.28122651 917.0229181 6135.679239 1084.589394 10.70688202 7.741277402
             08:00:00 124.1484465    17.14357927 948.9060481 6126.791479 1085.907147 10.76713085 7.810187162
             08:00:00 161.0455657    17.10409992 881.4517913 5839.73355  1073.585164 9.925269955 7.987206082
             08:00:00 165.645823     16.45928764 860.4285647 5781.612679 1073.439013 10.01297791 7.983672272"
  )
```

I presume the data should match the original data, but in replacing hours passed with just the hour of day, we've lost the date component and need to add it back. (You can skip this if you have a working timestamp already.) I'll assume today's date, 9/13/18 as the starting point.

```
timestamps <- lubridate::ymd_h(c(
  2018091308, 2018091311, 2018091314, 2018091317, 
  2018091320, 2018091408, 2018091708, 2018092008))

df_fix_times <- df %>%
  mutate(TIME = timestamps)
```

Now, we can reshape into a "tidy" format where each observation is in a row. This will make it easier to plot.

```
df_tidy <- df_fix_times %>%
  gather(series, value, -TIME)
```

And now we can use the `facet_wrap` call here to put each series in its own graph.

```
ggplot(df_tidy, aes(TIME, value, group = series)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~series, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: Hello.  many thanks for the above help.  However I am getting the below message when I try and run it:Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "function".  I have upload all the appropriate packages.  I have also upload the file as a .csv file.  Could that be a reason?

Comment: I think the problem is I accidentally omitted `library(dplyr)` at the step with the other library calls. (alternatively, one could use `library(tidyverse)` which happens to load all three of `ggplot2`, `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and a few other related packages. I'll edit above, pls let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: Hi Jon.  I loaded Tidyverse and its still giving the following message : Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "function".. It does not seem to be happy about the mutate function for some reason?

Comment: Hi Jon, I have also noticed with the code the time series graphs are not using the times set in the columns.  Therefore I have added an extra code:as.POSIXct(strptime(paste(bc$DATE, bc$TIME), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")).  The error is still there but it has now changed to an interger.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach if you want to create graphs in separate slides:

Step 1) Read the data

```
    df1 <-
  read.table(header = TRUE, row.names = NULL, text = 
               "TIME    15  16  17  18  20  22  23
0 hrs   130.4905899 15.44164769 948.9185939 6211.837354 1071.730556 10.08920076 7.793301031
3 Hrs   125.7301547 18.87143833 991.0009783 6304.471569 1082.126629 10.80475415 7.857773565
6 Hrs   153.3779662 17.63335938 949.1741247 6209.524186 1079.102756 10.68438383 8.326058855
8 Hrs   132.3256891 15.8961511  917.0452991 6123.402395 1081.166439 10.41007094 7.856372445
12 Hrs  130.6405835 15.28122651 917.0229181 6135.679239 1084.589394 10.70688202 7.741277402
24 Hrs  124.1484465 17.14357927 948.9060481 6126.791479 1085.907147 10.76713085 7.810187162
96 Hrs  161.0455657 17.10409992 881.4517913 5839.73355  1073.585164 9.925269955 7.987206082
168 hrs 165.645823  16.45928764 860.4285647 5781.612679 1073.439013 10.01297791 7.983672272")
```

Step 2)

```
library(ggplot2);library(tidyr);library(dplyr)
df_tidy <- df1 %>%
  mutate(TIME = row.names %>% as.integer) %>%
  select(-row.names) %>%
  gather(series, value, -TIME)
```

Step 3) Create graphs in slides one after other in ppt document

```
library(sqldf)

df2=sqldf("select distinct(series) from df_tidy")   


library(officer);library(ggplot2);library(magrittr);library(rvg)


doc <- read_pptx()
for (i in 1:nrow(df2))
                  {
                     data_graph_ind=df_tidy[(df_tidy$series==df2[i,1]),]
                     doc <- add_slide(doc, layout = "Two Content", master = "Office Theme")
                     doc <- doc %>% 
                     ph_with_text(type = "title",df2[i,1]) 

                     doc <- doc %>%
                     ph_with_vg(doc, ggobj=ggplot(data = data_graph_ind, aes(x = TIME, y = value)) + 
                                    geom_line()+geom_point(),type="body")
                     print(doc,target="C:/path/example.pptx")

                  }
```

Comment: Thanks.  Any advice on the rest of the code as the mutate function is still bring up errors.

Comment: I have just ran your office code and getting the following error.   Error in `[.data.frame`(df, i, 1) object 'i' not found.  Also which path should I select?

Comment: If you are using the same code I pasted, try putting "df2" instead of "df". Also, path can be any location on your system where you want to save the power point document. Please let me know if it works..

Comment: Hello.  Path sorted.  However script still not working, unsure where you want me to change the df2 instead of df?